# Função para retornar frequências de letras numa array

Tags: javascript, string, dicionário

Eu tava tentando fazer a função que consta no título, porém não obtive sucesso, ao olha o código solução para tal função, não consegui entender, segue o código:

```
    function letter_frequency(s) {
    let arr = [];
    let i = 0;
    let str = s.toUpperCase();
    while (i < str.length){
        let char = str.charAt(i);
        if (arr[char]!== undefined){
            arr[char]++;
        } else arr[char] = 1;

        i++
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Minha pergunta se refere ao scope do `if`. Digamos que recebemos uma `String "hello"`. Porque a letra H `(charAt[i] para i = 0;)` é considerada `undefined`?

Comment: JS tem umas coisas esquisitas e posso não saber de uma delas, mas pra mim isso é código ruim e não faz sentido. o `s` pode ser `undefined`. O código é tão ruim que faz 2 laços onde poderia fazer um só, e a pessoa que fez não percebeu isso, deve ter colocado esse `if` de alegre também porque viu algo parecido em algum lugar que manipulava outro tipo de objeto.

Comment: O código ta escrito errado nunca terá o efeito de contar frequência.

Comment: Não é a letra H que está sendo comparada com `undefined`, e sim `arr["H"]`. Basicamente, `arr[letra]` guarda a quantidade daquela letra, mas se for a primeira ocorrência dessa letra, `arr[letra]` ainda não existe, por isso verifica-se se é `undefined`

Comment: Agora que eu vi que ele está usando isso como dicionário.

Comment: Entendi a pergunta não é "porque o código não funciona" e sim "porque a letra testada é undefined"

Comment: Ele faz um laço na string da palavra e quando não encontrar uma letra na string, ou seja, enquanto ela **não** for undefined, significa que a letra não existe na string, ela define que a frequência é 1 (uma vez). Caso contrário, ele soma a quantidade de vezes que a letra se repete na string, tira o let e usa var... para entender: use: 'hello'.charAt(0); 'hello'.charAt(1);

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `if` em si ali está testando uma condição de um dicionário. Um dicionário é um objeto que tem vários elementos indexados por uma chave e esta chave pode ser qualquer valor válido.

Ele parece um pouco com um *array*, mas é diferente porque no *array* a chave é chamada de índice, só aceita um valor numérico inteiro em sequência, no caso do JS começando em 0 e terminando no número igual ao tamanho menos 1. No *array* todas as chaves dentro dessa faixa são chaves válidas, em um dicionário (também conhecido por *hashtable* ou *array* associativo ou mapa em certos contextos) não tem uma sequência, as chaves são esparsas então qualquer chave pode ou não existir nessa coleção de dados. Então essas coleções são um par de chave e valor, onde o que te interessa mais é o valor, mas é acessado através da chave.

A API do JavaScript escolheu que se você tentar acessar uma chave que não existe não dá erro, ele apenas resulta em um valor `undefined` porque se não tem a chave é claro que não tem o valor. Então o jeito de verificar se a chave não existe é exatamente ver se o valor resultante é `undefined`.

Neste código está pegando uma letra do parâmetro recebido e verificando se ela existe na coleção de dados, se ela não existe então a chave é criada com um valor inicial de 1, se ela já existe então apenas incrementa o valor de lá. Portanto essa coleção terá um elemento para cada letra diferente existente na *string* passada, quando a letra for repetida em vez de criar uma nova chave ele incrementa o contador de letras e assim obtém o que se espera, a contagem de frequência de letras.

Dá para fazer melhor isso, mas é uma forma válida.

Assim visualiza o que ocorre:

```js
 function letter_frequency(s) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let chave in s) {
        let char = s[chave].toUpperCase();
        if (arr[char] !== undefined) arr[char]++;
        else arr[char] = 1;
        for (let chave in arr) console.log(chave, "=>", arr[chave]);
        console.log("------");
    }
    return arr;
}

letter_frequency("Hello");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/LetterFrequency.js).

Answer (score 2):

Porque a solução utiliza um *array*, `arr`, como um mapa, sendo que a chave será a letra presente na *string* e o respectivo valor será a quantidade que ela se repete. Inicialmente esse *array* está vazio e, portanto, não existirá nenhuma letra associada nele. Isso implica que `arr['h']` retorne `undefined`.

```js
let arr = [];

console.log(arr['h']);
```

Portanto, se for `undefined`, é criado o índice no *array* e inicializado com o valor 1. Nas próximas iterações o índice existirá e não retornará mais `undefined` e quando isso acontecer será apenas incrementado o valor.

```js
let arr = [];

arr['h'] = 1;

console.log(arr['h']);
```

Ou seja, ao percorrer as letras da *string* sempre será retornado `undefined` quando for a primeira ocorrência dela. Nas próximas será apenas incrementado a quantidade.

## Utilizando o Map

Uma alternativa seria utilizar o próprio tipo `Map` para criar esse mapa:

```js
function frequency(text) {

  // Define o mapa que gerenciará as frequências
  const map = new Map();
  
  // Percorre as letras do texto
  for (let letter of text) {
  
    // Busca a quantidade de vezes que a letra já se repetiu, ou 0 para a primeira ocorrência
    let count = map.get(letter) || 0;
    
    // Atualiza a frequência incrementando-a
    map.set(letter, count+1);
  }
  
  // Retorna o mapa de frequências
  return map;
}

const frequencies = frequency("anderson");

// Exibe a frequência de cada letra
for (let [letter, total] of frequencies) {
  console.log(`A letra ${letter} repetiu ${total} vezes.`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, é o seguinte:

Ele verifica enquanto o array da letra **"não"** for indefinido, ou seja, quando ela entrar na regra de contagem e passa a somar os valores. A letra **H** no caso é definida, ou seja, oposto do que você está dizendo. e não é um array como você publicou, do tipo: `charAt[i]`, mesmo se comportando como tal, isso é uma função do javascript, que captura a posição da letra na string:

Por exemplo: `'Hello'.charAt(0) irá retornar "H";`
A função `String.charAt()` retornará a letra na posição da string `[0 => 'H', 1 => 'E', 2 => 'L', ...]`

O if no caso está testando a letra, considere que **i** seja 0, então na variável `char` terá a letra "H", ela é indefinida, certo, então ela entra no else, o **[negado+igual+igual]** ( !== ) está verificando se é diferente tanto o tipo, como seu valor.

Ou seja, se for um "H" ele entra no else e recebe o valor 1:

```
 let char = str.charAt(i);

`else arr[char] = 1;`
```

O `while` está incrementando a variável **i** , enquanto ela for menor que o total de letras da palavra, isso faz com que ele percorra letra a letra e atribua os valores da soma para elementos definidos, em todas as outras situações será `undefined`, e receberá o valor 1:

```
 if (arr[char]!== undefined){
     arr[char]++;
 }
```

Observe que o while faz isso para cada letra:

`arr[char]`irá somar quando for definido:

```
arr["H"]++
arr["E"]++
arr["L"]++ //aqui fará uma soma de vezes pois ele terá sido definido mais de uma vez
arr["O"]++
```

Ele vai passar pela regra de atribuição 5 vezes:

> 1º entrará no else, já que `arr[char]` ainda não foi definido, retornando o valor 1 para a posição da letra H.
>       2º entrará no else, já que `arr[char]` ainda não foi definido, retornando o valor 1 para a posição da letra E.
>       3º entrará no else, já que `arr[char]` ainda não foi definido, retornando o valor 1 para a posição da letra L.
>       4º entra na condição do if, uma vez que já tenha definido `arr[char]` com a letra L, ele se auto-somará: 2
>       5º entra no else novamente pois a letra O ainda não foi definida e coloca  o valor 1.

Você pode testar e ver isso acontecer da seguinte maneira no console do seu navegador:

```
function letter_frequency(s) {
    let arr = [];
    let i = 0;
    let str = s.toUpperCase();
    while (i < str.length){
        let char = str.charAt(i);
        if (arr[char]!== undefined){
            arr[char]++;
            console.log('definido',  arr[char], char)
        } else {arr[char] = 1;
            console.log('indefinido',  arr[char], char)
        }


        i++
    }
    return arr;
}
letter_frequency("Hello");
```