# Map com array e propriedade dinâmicos

Tags: javascript, array, map

Estou tentando criar uma função `map`, cujo array e propriedade a ser retornada sejam dinâmicas, isto é, possam ser passadas como parâmetro de uma função. Vamos tomar o array abaixo como caso de uso.

```
const students = [
    { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
    { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
    { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];
```

Minha primeira tentativa foi tornar apenas o array dinâmico, através de uma closure. Cheguei a este resultado, que funcionou:

```
let teste = array => array.map(({ name }) => name);
```

Nesse caso, eu posso passar qualquer array que tenha a propriedade `name` que ela será retornada.

Agora, eu preciso que a propriedade também seja dinâmica e possa ser chamada a partir do parâmetro da função. Algo mais ou menos assim: `getProperties(students, 'name')`.

Fiz o seguinte código, mas não funcionou:

```
const getProperties = (array, prop) => array.map(({ prop }) => prop);
```

O retorno foi `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`.
Podem me ajudar a resolver esse problema de como tornar a propriedade dinâmica também?

Comment: Apenas um adendo, vc poderia declarar como `function getProperties(array, prop) { return array.map(etc...); }` - não há nenhuma vantagem em usar *arrow function* nesse caso (e na minha opinião, o código fica até um pouco mais difícil de ler, e sem nenhum ganho de fato): https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/33040926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do seu exemplo é que o prop como é uma string não referencia diretamente a um nome de atributo do objeto. Você pode tentar fazer assim:

```js
const getProperties = (array, prop) => array.map((element) => element[prop]);
console.log(getProperties);
```

Answer (score 5):

Com este código que você tentou utilizar:

> ```
> const getProperties = (array, prop) => array.map(({ prop }) => prop);
> ```

Você está mapeando o `array` do primeiro parâmetro para um outro *array* que irá ser formado através da propriedade `prop` do *array* que você passar. Da forma como você fez a desestruturação, ela não é dinâmica, mas sim estática.

Veja, se todos os objetos tivessem a propriedade `prop`, o seu código funcionaria normalmente:

```js
const students = [
  { prop: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
  { prop: 'John', grade: 4 },
  { prop: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

const getProperties = (array) =>
  array.map(({ prop }) => prop);
  
console.log(getProperties(students));
```

Nesse caso, então, o parâmetro `prop` nem faz diferença, tanto é que eu o removi.

Se você quiser acessar a propriedade dinamicamente, pode utilizar a [notação de colchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), que te permite esse acesso dinâmico.

Algo assim:

```js
const students = [
  { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
  { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
  { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

const getProperties = (array, prop) =>
  array.map((obj) => obj[prop]);
  
console.log(getProperties(students, 'name'));
```

Note no código acima que a desestruturação não foi mais utilizada como antes, já que era estática na forma como havia sido utilizada. Você tinha colocado a propriedade `prop` de forma "*hard-coded*" no código.

Como alternativa, você ainda pode utilizar a desestruturação utilizando propriedades computadas. [Eu expliquei melhor sobre isso nesta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/430325/69296)

```js
const students = [
  { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
  { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
  { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

const getProperties = (array, prop) =>
  array.map(({ [prop]: value }) => value);
  //            ↑↑↑↑
  
console.log(getProperties(students, 'name'));
```

Note, no código acima, que a desestruturação é dinâmica, já que estamos utilizando propriedades computadas.

Eu pessoalmente prefiro a primeira opção — me parece mais clara. Mas como tudo na programação, existem diversas formas para se atingir o mesmo objetivo. Quis demonstrar duas delas. :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas me ajuda a entender porque a notação de ponto não funciona no seu primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Não funciona porque a notação de ponto é estática, mas não dinâmica, compreende? :)

Comment: Agora entendi. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode acessar a propriedade da maneira `objeto[prop]`.

Ao tentar usar o `({ prop })` você estará procurando por um atributo chamado `prop`. Então, como a `prop` é uma variável, o melhor caminho seria:

1. Receber como parâmetro do `map` o objeto inteiro `(obj)`
2. Acessar a `prop` em questão com `obj[prop]`.

```js
const students = [
    { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
    { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
    { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

const getProperties = (array, prop) => array.map((obj) => obj[prop]);

console.log(getProperties(students, 'name'))

console.log(getProperties(students, 'grade'))
```

Comment: Obrigado. Me ajuda a entender porque a notação de ponto não funcionaria nesse exemplo.

Comment: Conforme [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation), a notação de ponto acessa `objeto.nomeDoAtributo`, então ao usar o `.prop`, ele interpretará como `prop` sendo o nome do atributo, enquanto `objeto[nomeDoAtributo]` pode receber uma string: `objeto['nome']` ou uma variável `objeto[prop]`

Comment: Muito obrigado. Entendi.