# Erro do ESLint: "Must use destructuring state assignment"

Tags: javascript, react, eslint

Alguém poderia me informar o que estou fazendo de errado? O erro "*Must use destructuring state assignment*" está no `{this.state.time}`.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
     time: '00:00:00',
  };
}

render() {
   const { time } = this.state;
   return (
     <div>
        <h1>
         Hora
          {this.state.time}
         </h1>
     </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse erro é de uma regra do ESLint: *Enforce consistent usage of destructuring assignment of props, state, and context ([react/destructuring-assignment](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md))*.

Em tradução livre, esta regra serve para ter um uso consistente do estado (*state*), das *props* e do contexto (*context*) através da [desestruturação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430322/100416). Para corrigir o erro, você pode:

1. Obedecer a regra:

```
render() {
  const { time } = this.state; // Você já tinha essa linha no código
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Hora
        {time} {/* Aqui você usa `time` ao invés de `this.state.time` */}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}}
```

<sup>Nota: Se você tentar fazer `const time = this.state.time` terá o erro novamente, pois não estará acessando via desestruturação.</sup>

2. Desabilitar a regra no seu arquivo `eslintrc` ou nas configurações do ESLint no package.json, assim a regra não será mais aplicada em nenhum lugar:

```
"rules": {
  "react/destructuring-assignment": ['off']
}
```

Esta é uma **regra para consistência no código**. Deixar a regra habilitada fará com que você e seu time acessem à variáveis da mesma maneira (com a desestruturação). Deixar a regra desabilitada não trará penalidades ao seu código do tipo "estou fazendo algo errado", apenas não forçará uma consistência.

Portanto, qualquer uma das duas opções acima são válidas e a preferência por uma ou outra parte do desenvolvedor e do consenso da equipe.

Comment: Era exatamente este o problema. Muito obrigado amigo!